# Setting decimal scale based on a column value

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting

I query two values from a table. I want to use the second value to set the decimal scale of the first value. Would anyone know how to set this using `to_char`? I was looking at the formats and I'm not sure how to make the int I'm receiving into the format I need. Here is my code:

```
with tmp as (select num, scale
        from tl)
select fun, num
from fun_table f, tmp
where f.fun = tmp.scale;
```

EDIT:
if I receive num as 5.87 and scale as 3 I want the result to be 5.870

num: 7.00 scale: 1 expected output: 7.0

num: 7 scale: 4 expected output: 7.0000

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: just added, let me know if you need more info

Comment: Your query includes two tables, tl and fun_table. Is that sample data for those tables?

Comment: the sample data is from tl table which gets stored in tmp. The second select statement is the output I need, only i need to set the num output value to have the decimal scale of the tmp.scale value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(num, CONCAT('99D',RPAD('9',scale,'9'))) FROM tl
```

or, if `scale` can be 0 and you don't want to show the decimal separator in such cases,

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(num, CONCAT('99',RPAD('D',scale+1,'9'))) FROM tl
```

Tested on Oracle Database 11g.

Comment: I think this might be right! I dont have access to test it at the moment but I will make this the correct answer (or comment back if its not) when i can test! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
select round(fun,scale) from fun_table f, tmp where f.fun = tmp.scale;
```

Maybe this is what you're looking for? Depending on the logic you want you may want to replace round function with floor or ceil.

Comment: wouldn't this just round the fun value to the numth place? I dont want to round any of the data i am recieving just set the scale

Comment: Oh I see, sorry for the confusion. Then you may need to convert the value to char since there is no difference between 7.0 and 7.00 for a number variable. the syntax for oracle is to_char(num, '9999.99') where the 9s after the '.' in second parameter represents the number of scales you wish to display. You may also need to figure out how to construct the second parameter('9999.99') depending on the scale column though.

Comment: All good, thanks for trying. I'm just not sure how to turn the int value into the format I need to set the scale in to to_char function. That what i was hoping to get help with haha